# How to send JSON every 3 seconds with websocket [Python server, js client]

Tags: python, websocket, timer

I have my server with Python that send JSON via websocket, the code is like this:

```py
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets
import json
import threading

stopSignal = 0

def stopTestINT():
    print("test Stop \n")
    stopSignal = 1

async def wsjson(websocket, path):

    while True:

        data = datetime.datetime.now()

        randomINT = random.randint(1, 101)

        sensors_data = {
                'property': {
                    'INT': randomINT,
                    'stop' : stopSignal
                    } 
            }

        timer = threading.Timer(15.0, stopTestINT)  

        if randomINT < 80:
            timer.start()
        else:
            timer.cancel()

        print_json = json.dumps(sensors_data)

        await websocket.send(print_json)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)


start_server = websockets.serve(wsjson, '127.0.0.1', 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

with this example code I send every 3 seconds this json but in the client I recieve (every 3 seconds) three randomINT. Why?

**1.** And, when I close connection (in JS, with ws.close() ) the connection is not closed, infact I recieve this error:

```
Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\*\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\server.py", line 169, in handler
    yield from self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "C:\Users\*\**\websockets py\websjson.py", line 160, in wsjson
    await websocket.send(print_json)
  File "C:\Users\**\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 462, in send
    yield from self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Users\*\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 646, in ensure_open
    ) from self.transfer_data_exc
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1005 (no status code [internal]), no reason
```

**2.** And the timer does not work, infact in prompt I see every 3 seconds "test Stop".

in theory, I wanted as soon as a randomint> 80 arrives, then the timer stops and starts again when it finds a number <80.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `time.sleep(X)` instead of timer in your `while True` statement.